# How to add security tab to the drive properties in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, properties

I can't seem to access security tab for my drive E: in Windows 10. The one when you go to properties:

[image]

I tried all recommended methods I could find online but they don't work for Windows 10.

Any idea how Microsoft wants us to enable it now?

Comment: Change your file system, FAT, it's missing by design. (actually don't because it's suppose to be fat, and be missing, by design )

Comment: @Ramhound: Oh shoot! I get it. Been doing it for too long today... need a break.... thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Already mentioned in the comments, FAT does not offer any Security in terms of permissions. Change your Filesystem to NTFS and you will see the security tab.
Before you change the Filesystem, save all your Data somewhere else.

Comment: It's a 10MB partition... With 10KB used.

Comment: 7.3MB partition actually

Comment: Well...10mb could hold a password container, some important documents or nothing which is much more likely but better mention it then receive the blame afterwards.

Answer (score -2):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xOSBZ3U2MzM

Open a command prompt window (As Administrator!)

Enable Security tab:
REG add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer /v Nosecuritytab /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

Disable Security tab:
REG add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer /v Nosecuritytab /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f